# How to take input from the user in Javascript, while loading the code.

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my demo code:

```
while (true) {
// Part one: Execute this code

input = prompt("Enter input"); // Now wait for user input

// Part two: Now execute this after getting user input

}
```

But, it is not working like I shown in the comments. It first asks the user for input, then loads part one and part two on the screen.

Comment: If part one contains code that uses callbacks, it won't show up immediately. You need to provide more code.

Comment: It doesn't - it executes in the order you have it there.  Please modify the code to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: The browser is single threaded - if you stop that thread to prompt the user, then it won't be able to refresh the page (your part one) first.

Comment: um, highly doubt it....

Comment: could you provide more code? The closest to real scenario the better

Comment: Here's an example demonstrating that DOM changes are reflected in the DOM until *after* the prompt has completed:  https://jsfiddle.net/sa5ownd8/

Comment: I want to display the document.write text before prompt loads, see the example here: https://jsfiddle.net/sa5ownd8/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While executing JavaScript, browsers accumulate all changes to the DOM before doing a re-render. The `prompt` dialog delays completion of the JavaScript thread and delays the re-render operation.

To allow the browser to render accumulated changes, put the `prompt` and any subsequent operations in a `setTimeout` function.

```
document.write("I Want to Display this before Prompt");
$("div").addClass("blue")
setTimeout(function() {
    input = prompt("test");
    //PUT more code here
});
```

The `setTimeout` will hold its code block for the next render tick of the browser.